# Cannot resolve symbol TreeMap on import

Tags: java, android, import, treemap

The code was compiled in android studio (API 23). When I tried to run this code again in a week, the class file became corrupted, when I used the old version and decompiled of this class, it turned out that the `TreeMap` in java does not exist although in documentation it was added in API 1.

Tried to Invalidate Caches and Restart. Is there an opportunity to use `TreeMap` or something else with the same functionality?

[image: Imports]

**UPDATE:** The program has compiled despite this.

Comment: Could it be that you are importing some other `TreeMap` before? What is the exact error on the import?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki "cannot resolve symbol 'TreeMap'" and "unused import statement" on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the program compiles but you see errors in Android Studio it's a problem with project definition in Android Studio. This is often solved by following steps:

1. Check that project has the right Android SDK configured
2. If point 1 doesn't help, restart Android Studio
3. If point 2 doesn't help, re-importing project
4. if point 3 doesn't help, use `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` option which will force a big re-index operation.

Comment: it helped, compile sdk version was newer.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your import looks like this:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
```

Comment: yes, but it even does not show TreeMap in autocompletions in util directory.

Comment: Then reimport SDK's(java + android) in Project Structure and Invalidate Caches / Restart again.